# How to interpret a multi-variable regression model?

Tags: regression, self-study, interpretation

How do I interpret this predictive model?

> S&P500 Next Week = Earnings Per Share * 0.25 + Dividends Per Share *
>   -1.519 + Current S&P500* 1.018 + 5.409

Comment: Hi there, is this homework?

Comment: Consider is like homework.

Comment: Should we tag this time-series?

Comment: @gung I don't think it matters either way. :)

Answer (score 3):

You have a model that says the `S&P500 rating for next week` can be predicted off three variables:

1. `Earnings Per Share`
2. `Dividends Per Share`
3. `Current S&P500`
4. and the model has an intercept term as well (the last number). The intercept is the value for `S&P500 Next Week` when the three predictor variables in your model are all [what?]. What does the intercept tell us about whether all of the value of `S&P500 Next Week` is predicted off the three variables?

Each predictor variable has a number multiplier associated with it:

1. `0.25` which is for `Earnings Per Share`
2. `-1.519` which is for `Dividends Per Share`
3. `1.018` which is for `Current S&P500`

What is each multiplier telling you about how the predictor variables affect the predicted value of `S&P500 Next Week`? Look at the size of the effect, as well as the sign of the effect.

Comment: @gung thanks, I used to do the odd bit of remedial coaching for first-year stats students. :) You and the others are pretty darn good yourselves too.